# aws s3 cp error "variable 'current_index' referenced before assignment"

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to download a file (about 2T) to my local server from s3 such like:

```
aws s3 cp s3://outputs/star_output.tar.gz ./ --profile abcd --endpoint-url=https://abc.edu
```

It seems the downloadeing finished with a file like `star_output.tar.gz.9AB04cEd` but ended up with a failure:

```
download failed: s3://outputs/star_output.tar.gz to ./ local variable 'current_index' referenced before assignment
```

And the file `star_output.tar.gz.9AB04cEd` was also automatically deleted.

I tried a small text file and it downloaded no issue. Is this related to the size of the file (too big)?

Anyone knows the possible reason?

Comment: That honestly sounds like a bug.  How recently have you updated your `aws` command?

Comment: I am not sure. It maintains by another IT person but I have tried two servers and got same error.